# Avoid Plotting Redundant Pixels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When I'm making qq-plots (basically a scatter-plot), I frequently use matplotlib, occasionally Seaborn. If I happen to have a few million data-points (let's say 8 million), plotting can take forever. I've frequently found myself waiting 15+ minutes just to have a plot output to a png or pdf. Same problem with R, actually.

I've tried many tricks to work around this. pngs save faster than pdfs. I've tried only plotting the top 10% of the larger of my two datasets and hiding it behind the smaller one, figuring that visually it won't be apparent (unless you're squinting). I've tried down-sampling my larger dataset, which works 'okay', but I have to put a lot of work in up-front to make sure none of the important points get down-sampled, and the resulting plot tends to end up looking sparse.

My go-to lately has been to try a combination of the above methods until I have a plot that looks okay, and then to bite the bullet and wait the entire 15+ minutes to plot the whole dataset when I'm ready. I hate that I have to do this. MatLab does some weird magic to spit the same plot out in seconds, but I hate using MatLab and I don't really know the language that well. My understanding is that MatLab somehow achieves this by calculating redundant pixels first, and only plotting necessary pixels. Is there any truth to this? Is it possible to replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting a lot of duplicates, what about just dedupping?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import timeit

x = np.random.randint(0, 10**3, 8*10**6)
y = np.random.randint(0, 10**3, 8*10**6)

points = list(zip(x, y))
dedupped_points = list(set(points))

# About 12.5% in my example
print(len(dedupped_points) / len(points))
```

If you don't expect *exact* duplicates, you can always remove *near*-duplicates by rounding.

```
x = 100*np.random.rand(8*10**6)
y = 100*np.random.rand(8*10**6)

dec_points = list(zip(x, y))

x_rounded = np.round(x, 2)
y_rounded = np.round(y, 2)

dec_round_points = list(set(zip(x_rounded, y_rounded)))

# Again, about 12.5% for me
print(len(dec_round_points) / len(dec_points))
```

Comment: When checking timings, you would want to see how long it takes to *draw* the image, not create the python object. So you need `start...; plt.plot(...); plt.gcf().canvas.draw(); stop...`

Comment: Good point. I just removed the plotting, as it's unnecessary.

Comment: Definitely a good suggestion. I think this is a good idea, and am looking at how it works in practice. Intuitively, the greater the resolution I render the images in, the worse this solution is going to work. The rounding should correspond to the resolution of the image as well, else you're going to end up with gaps (and we're back at square A). I'll get back to you.

Comment: I totally agree @JohnRouhana about the resolution issue. It might be interesting to just write a custom rounding function that chooses the precision based on the plotted resolution.